# spring batch JdbcPagingItemReader job restart and select only records that have not been selected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

How can I implement fault tolerant spring batch job with restartability. I have a table with **8 Milion** records, then configured a job with   **JdbcPagingItemReader** reader to fetch records and **AmqpItemWriter** to queue records to **rabbitMQ**. Challange is that when I stop the job abruptly, then restart, I get an Exception. Expected behavior:

1. restart the job successfully
2. Start reading the table from the id the job stopped from

Below are the configs:

```
@Bean
public JdbcPagingItemReader<NotificationRequest> notificationRequestJdbcPagingItemReader() {
    JdbcPagingItemReader<NotificationRequest> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();

    reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    reader.setFetchSize(1000);
    reader.setRowMapper(new SmsSQLRowMapper());

    PostgresPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new PostgresPagingQueryProvider();
    queryProvider.setSelectClause("subscriber_fk, event_time, record_flag, batch_date, message_type, cents_loanable, request_id, reason_code");
    queryProvider.setFromClause("from tbl_sms_tracker_new");

    Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>(1);

    sortKeys.put("request_id", Order.ASCENDING);

    queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

    reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);

    return reader;
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<NotificationRequest> notificationRequestAmqpItemWriter() {
    AmqpTemplate aTemplate = (AmqpTemplate) applicationContext.getBean("amqpTemplate");

    AmqpItemWriter<NotificationRequest> itemWriter = new AmqpItemWriter<>(aTemplate);

    return itemWriter;
}


@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("notificationStep1")
            .<NotificationRequest, NotificationRequest>chunk(1000)
            .reader(notificationRequestJdbcPagingItemReader())
            .writer(notificationRequestAmqpItemWriter())
            .faultTolerant()
            .build();
}


@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("notificationJob")
            .start(step1())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Expected behavior:
>
> 1. restart the job successfully

If you stop the job abruptly (`kill -9`), then the `JobRepository` has no way of knowing what is the current status of your job because no one told it before. Your job may still be in the status `STARTED` while it isn't (it was killed). That's why you get an exception when trying to restart a killed job. You have to tell the job repository manually that you know that the execution either failed or should be considered aborted. More details about this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job

> 2. Start reading the table from the id the job stopped from

When you stop the job abruptly, the current execution context is not saved correctly to the job repository. In this case, when you restart the job, the item reader will read data from the last "savepoint", ie the last successfully persisted execution context. However, if you stop your job gracefully, the expected behaviour you mentioned will be honored.